# Gmail Java APIs to use service account with OAuth 2.0

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api, google-workspace

I am new to the Google API. I have a google workspace account registered with its own domain.
I would like to be able to perform actions on users mailboxes using the google java api.
I was using the [quick start](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) project and played with authentications as scopes.

I can perform actions on the user account that I performed my OAuth consent.

looking at the example

```
 String user = "me";
            ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users()
           .labels().list(user).execute();
```

It uses the "me" keyword as the user, I would like to use one of the users in the account and perform the same action.
When I switch the "me" to one of the users in my domain I get the following.

```
GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/user@somedomain.what.ever/labels
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Delegation denied for admin@mirncast.uk",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Delegation denied for admin@mirncast.uk",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

As far as I understand from the above I need to provide [user delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation).
User delegation requires a service account.
So I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://skaaptjop.medium.com/access-gsuite-apis-on-your-domain-using-a-service-account-e2a8dbda287c)

My code ended up as

```
Set<String> scope = Collections.singleton(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);

GoogleCredential credentialFromJson = GoogleCredential
        .fromStream(new FileInputStream(
                "/certificate.json"))
       .createScoped(scope);

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountId(credentialFromJson.getServiceAccountId())
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(credentialFromJson.getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
        .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM))
        .setServiceAccountUser("user@somedomain.what.ever")
        //.setServiceAccountUser("service@custom-octagon-1234567.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
        .build();


Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("remediation service").build();

String user = "user@somedomain.what.ever";
final var messagesResponse = service.users().messages().list(user).execute();
System.out.println(messagesResponse.getMessages().stream().map(message -> message.getId()).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

**This code has a few problems.**

I was only able to make it work when I set the setServiceAccountUser with the same email address I am trying to access. Using the API that way defeat the purpose from my point of view.
when using the service account I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/hraman@gsuite-dev.mirncast.uk/messages
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Precondition check failed.",
    "reason" : "failedPrecondition"
  } ],
  "message" : "Precondition check failed.",
  "status" : "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}
```

The example uses deprecated API GoogleCredential and I cann't figure what is the latest API for this based on OAuth2 authentication

My maven dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev20210301-1.31.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.31.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: So it works when you delegate to  "user@somedomain.what.ever"?

Comment: Yes, but that is an actual user no the service account, I would expect to provide it only at the service level service.users().messages().list("user@somedomain.what.ever")

Comment: As long as you have added .setServiceAccountUser("user@somedomain.what.ever") i would expect that to work just like using me.  However not sure why you wouldn't just use me.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to understand that gmail data is private user data, only the owner of that data can access that data, or applications which have been authorized by the user to access that data.   In the case of gsuite domain accounts, the domain admin can also grant permissions to others to impersonate the original user, but impersonation is still the user accessing the data. Its just acting like its the original user. (understanding this concept will be important soon)

You need to understand that a service account is just a dummy user. It has its own google drive account, and google calendar account, it can also send emails as if it had a gmail account. So like you it can only by default access its own private data.

Now using gsuite we can delegate the users permissions allowing them to impersonate another user "user@somedomain.what.ever"

So it can be set up so that `"service@custom-octagon-1234567.iam.gserviceaccount.com"` is allowed to impersonate `"user@somedomain.what.ever"` and perform actions on their behalf. Only for this to work in code you must state which user you are currently impersonating in this case we use `setServiceAccountUser` if you dont do that then you are just `"service@custom-octagon-1234567.iam.gserviceaccount.com"` and can only access the data belonging to `"service@custom-octagon-1234567.iam.gserviceaccount.com"`

As for accessing data with [messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) the following commands are interchangeable.

```
service.users().messages().list("user@somedomain.what.ever")
service.users().messages().list("me")
```

With the exception of if the first option is not the email address of the currently authenticated user, or the impersonating user it will fail.  By impersonating a user you are in fact that user so the API sees the service account as `"user@somedomain.what.ever"` without specifying the impersonation you are just normal old service account who can only access their data.

There needs to be a way of specifying that all calls coming from the service account are now on behalf of this user that's why you need to set `setServiceAccountUser` to the user you wish to impersonate.

Comment: I can see your point about setServiceAccountUser and the use of me.
But I am still confused about the OAuth 2.0 in this context. 
It looks like I need to obtain the token for every request as in my case I will be repeating the same action for a few users in my domain.
So will the auth 2.0 consent step will still happen once this is confusing anyway as we are talking about the server to server mode here. I would expect my customer to define and accept once the service account and then it should be used automatically

Comment: Well you see service accounts aren't really Oauth2. Standard Oauth2 is 3LO, service accounts are  2LO.  Which step is it repeating?  You are yes going to have to connect to each user but you would need to do that if you were running 3LO and using a refresh token.

Comment: Let me look at 3LO

Comment: 2LO or Oauth1:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account  or this if you want a nap https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849

Comment: 3LO or Oauth2:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app or more bedtime reading https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749

Comment: It looks like 2LO is at the admin level
https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/art/admin/en/cpanel/2-legged-oauth-diagram.png while 3LO will ask the user itself https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/art/admin/en/cpanel/3-legged-oauth-diagram.png. The organisation is the one that setting the rules as this app will be used as part of the organisation policy. But 2LO is deprecated

Comment: Service accounts in Google are not depicted.

Comment: Maybe I am confused but it says here  https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/04/saying-goodbye-to-oauth-10-2lo.html that 2L0 is deprecated and I guess 2LO and service account is not the same thing. But the API used in my example is marked as deprecated in the code

Comment: Nope not the same that was client login like sending a login and password check the section with **The easiest way to migrate to the new standard is to use OAuth 2.0 service accounts with domain-wide delegation.**    Service accounts are a special type of 2LO not really 2LO but close.    Explaining my opinion of how they have service accounts working in the authorization server is a longer conversation.  IMO its a home grown solution by google.